# How to get data in singletone class using intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, singleton

I am implementing music application where I have to pass some string data(url of song) from activity to Singletone class using intent and set it to mediaplayer instance which is in singletone class.I am getting error at  getIntent().giving error as The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Singletone class.

```
Intent iin=getIntent().getExtras();
         Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
            if(b!=null)
            {
                j =(String) b.get("new_variable_name");
            }
```

Comment: Question is not clear, please explain the context more clearly , and show some code may be somebody could help you

Answer (score 1):

In singleton class, you have the onCreate() method and inside you can get the data from bundle:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String j;

if (extras != null) {
    j= extras.getString("new_variable_name");     
}
```

Comment: add some explanation to you answer

Comment: In Singletone class, you have the onCreate() method,inside the onCreate method write the above code to get the data from bundle.